# Adding CSS to Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I want to add/modify CSS to my v-data-table header and cell rows and I searched official documentation and searched on google but none of the solutions worked.
As per the different solutions I tried to add CSS Classes and templates for the headers but none of them seems to be working for me.
I am working on the Vue for the first time :)

here is my code:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :search="search"
  :items="PendingApprovals"
      multi-sort
      v-model="selected"
    show-select
    item-key="id"    
    show-expand
    hide-default-footer="true"
    disable-pagination = "true"
    class="elevation-1 mytable">

    <template v-slot:[`item.DateSubmitted`]="{ item }">
      {{FormatDate(item.raw.DateSubmitted)}}
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.Download`]="{ item }">    
      <a :href="DownloadUrl +item.raw.id">
      <v-icon size="small" class="me-2">
        mdi-download
      </v-icon>
    </a>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:[`item.Edit`]="{ item }">               
        <a :href="/form/+item.raw.id">
        <v-icon size="small" class="me-2">
        mdi-pencil
      </v-icon>
      </a>
  
    </template>

  </v-data-table>


export default {
    components: {
      VDataTable, 
  },
    data () {
      return {
        dialog: false,
      DownloadUrl : process.env.VUE_APP_API_BASE_URL + "JournalEx/Example/",      
      PendingApprovals:[],
      selected: [],
      ApproveDenyValues: [],
      search:'',

      rules: {
      required: (value) => !!value || "Denial Reason is a required field"
      },

      snackbar: false,
      snackbartext: '',
      timeout: 3000,

      headers: [
        {
          key: 'JournalTest',
          title: 'ID',
          align: 'start',
        },
        { title: 'IPS CASE', key: 'CaseCode', width: '20%' },
        { title: 'REQUEST REASON', key: 'Reason',  width: '30%'},
        { title: 'REQUESTED BY', key: 'RequestedBy' ,  width: '15%'},
        { title: 'DATE SUBMITTED', key: 'DateSubmitted'},
        { title: 'DOWNLOAD', key: 'Download',sortable:false},
        { title: 'EDIT', key: 'Edit', sortable: false },

      ], 
      }
    }
}
```

Here are some of the CSS I tried but did not work for me. not sure why:

```
<style scoped>
.v-data-table >>> .v-data-table-header {
  background-color: red !important;
}

::v-deep .v-data-table-header {
  background-color: #DCDCDC;
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is maybe obvious but just write CSS wherever? You could give your table an id and just style '#tableId th' and so on..

Comment: I have removed the template with table which i had added for testing purpose. my mistake. Also i tried adding css for table th/td but the changes are not reflecting for header and rows

Comment: This could be CSS Specificity https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity. Try adding !important to be sure.

Comment: added !important but still not working

Comment: Where did you add the styling? In the component?

Comment: I added them in main.css and tried to apply them as class. and also tried to add them in style tag in the same page but none of the methods worked

Comment: You are styling Vue names and not actual elements.. Could you retry by just using 'th' ?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue with following CSS code :

```
.v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > td,
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr th,
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr > td,
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr th {
      background-color: #f9f5e3 !important;
    }
    
    
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table > thead > tr > th,
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr > th {
      background-color: #D14081 !important;
    }
    
    
    .v-data-table-header__content {
      background-color: #D14081 !important;
      color: #CCF5AC;
      font-weight: bold;
    }


    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) > td,
    .v-data-table .v-table__wrapper > table tbody > tr:nth-of-type(even) th {
      background-color: #e4e0d0 !important;
    }
```